# How to check if $id is not set

Tags: php

So I got this bit of code where I need to check if id is not set.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$genrer = mysql_query("SELECT id, overskrift, brodtekst FROM rb_genrer WHERE id=$id");
while($ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)) {
    if (!isset($_GET["id"])){
        echo "Vælg en underside";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='overskrift'><h2>" . $ge["overskrift"] . "</h2></div> <p>" . $ge["brodtekst"] . "</p>";
    }
}
```

It works fine when I type in `genrer.php?id=1` in the URL, but when I type just `genrer.php` it doesn't output the "Vælg en underside"

Comment: That is because you don't have an ID so your query won't run. Therfor no while loop and no if statement

Comment: You are checking for the id **inside** the while loop, which will run **only** when there is an id.

Comment: Your query throws an error if you put id= empty. You should use "... WHERE id = '$id'"; to solve that.

Furthermore remember that issue has one problem with a numeric 0. PHP identifies 0 as false aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
    if (!isset($_GET["id"])){
         echo "Vælg en underside";
    } else {        
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $genrer = mysql_query("SELECT id, overskrift, brodtekst FROM rb_genrer WHERE id=$id");
        while($ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)) {               
                echo "<div class='overskrift'><h2>" . $ge["overskrift"] . "</h2></div> <p>" . $ge["brodtekst"] . "</p>";                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass an `id` to `genrer.php`, the script does not output the "Vælg en underside", because `$ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)` yields `false` from the start and thus the body of the `while` loop is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !$_GET['id']){
    echo "Vælg en underside";
} else {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $genrer = mysql_query("SELECT id, overskrift, brodtekst FROM rb_genrer WHERE id=$id");
    while($ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)) {
        echo "<div class='overskrift'><h2>" . $ge["overskrift"] . "</h2></div> <p>" . $ge["brodtekst"] . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
if (!isset($_GET["id"])){
     echo "Vælg en underside";
} else { 
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $genrer = mysql_query("SELECT id, overskrift, brodtekst FROM rb_genrer WHERE id=$id");
    while($ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)) {

            echo "<div class='overskrift'><h2>" . $ge["overskrift"] . "</h2></div> <p>" . $ge["brodtekst"] . "</p>";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if(isset($id)){
    $genrer = mysql_query("SELECT id, overskrift, brodtekst FROM rb_genrer WHERE id=$id");
    while($ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)) {
         echo "<div class='overskrift'><h2>" . $ge["overskrift"] . "</h2></div> <p>" . $ge["brodtekst"] . "</p>";
    }
}else
    echo "Vælg en underside";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you not set the $id the query not execute and so the while loop not work. Thats why it does not echo  Vælg en underside.
Try this

```
if (!isset($_GET["id"])){
     echo "Vælg en underside";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make it fallback on a default value.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '0');
$genrer = mysql_query("SELECT id, overskrift, brodtekst FROM rb_genrer WHERE id=$id");
while($ge = mysql_fetch_array($genrer)) {
    if (!isset($id)){
        echo "Vælg en underside";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='overskrift'><h2>" . $ge["overskrift"] . "</h2></div> <p>" . $ge["brodtekst"] . "</p>";
    }
}
```